# Is there any way to open nw.js app from web browser?

Tags: node.js, nwjs

I have a desktop application, packaged using node-webkit JS. Is there any way to open this app with IP address from other computer by browser? I just set `node-remote` to  `http://localhost:3000` in `package.json` but is not working when I use chrome and open the IP. There are some errors like `nw is not defiend` and etc. Please tell me if this way can work or not. Thanks

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know nwjs but if I understand correctly, you want to access to localhost in your computer from another computer.

you can not use ip to access because of NAT. but fortunaly you can do that by a third computer (that is not behind NAT). to do that use [localtunel](https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel).

for more info see [this](https://medium.com/@MicroPyramid/how-to-access-development-server-publicly-using-localtunnel-a9384ee6631d).

Answer (score 0):

Do you think you could paste what your package.json looks like? I've done what you are talking about. Here is what my file structure looks like:

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCDvP.png)

The package.json that is in my project folder:

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOaoQ.png)

---

The 1st thing that I did was install my dependencies into my project folder so that I don't get the `command not recognized` error. I did that by going to my project folder and typing:

```
npm init -y
npm install nw@0.50.1-sdk nwjs-builder -D
```

This creates a fresh `package.json` and adds the modules to the file as dependencies. Then I went into my src folder and created another `package.json`. I set the "main" tag to my `index.html`

Going back to the `.json` in my root project folder, we add to the "script" tag:

```
"script": {
  "dev": "nw src/ --remote-debugging-port=9222"
}
```

(you can make dev whatever you want)

Once you have that setup, all you need to do is run `npm run dev` and your app will open up. Head over to chrome and type `localhost:9222` and you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create an app that can run in a regular browser, and also in NW.js with added features when it runs inside NW.js. You would need to basically wrap anything in if statements, like

```js
if (window.nw) {
  let fs = window.nw.require('fs');
  let file = fs.readFileSync('./whatever.txt');
  console.log(String(file));
}
```

You could then create two different npm scripts. One to just run a local web server and one to run it and launch NW.js.

```json
{
  "main": "http://localhost:4467",
  "node-remote": "http://localhost:4467",
  "node-main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run serve\" \"wait-on http://localhost:4467 && nw .\"",
    "serve": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "latest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "latest",
    "wait-on": "latest"
  }
}
```

Example: https://github.com/nwutils/nw-local-server-example